# showSettingsAlert() function meaning

Tags: java, android

in location service class what does this function mean ?
 please simplify it because we are new developers

```
public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // Setting Icon to Dialog
        //alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.delete);

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this is is an alert letting the user know location services are not enabled. The positive response button (OK/Yes) opens the Settings app on the location settings page.

This function does not check whether location services are enabled, it just shows the alert. You need to call this function from within something that does check this.